# Message location/index in a queue (SQS or RabbitMQ)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, queue, amazon-sqs

I'm interested in finding the location of a message in a FIFO queue. The goal is to be able to display to a user "You are 3rd in line", then "You are 2nd in line", then "Your request is being processed". I have access to AWS SQS and RabbitMQ. I know I can get the total number of messages in the queue, I just don't know where the message I care about is located. So far I have read docs on the queuing technologies, but haven't seen a solution, so no code has been written yet. Has anyone else been able to successfully find the index/location of a single message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It isn't possible to get an item's "index".**

What you can do though, is get an estimate of wait time (interestingly enough, this concept is very similar to [how Disneyland measures wait time in their lines](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Disney-Parks-estimate-the-wait-time-in-line-for-the-attractions)):

1. Measure the following datapoints (and know when they change):

   - `parallelism` - How many items are processed in parallel?
   - `processingTime` - How long does it take an item to be processed?
   - `queueLength` - How many items are in the queue?
2. Calculate estimate:

   - `waitTimeOfNextItem = queueLength * processingTime / parallelism`

For example, if you have 100 items in the queue and each will take around 10 seconds to process, and you process 4 at once, then it'll take `100*10/4` or 250 seconds to process all the items. If a 101st item were to be put into the queue, you could estimate it would start processing after 250 seconds.

If your `processingTime` varies a lot, you can do calculations like rolling average or sampling, or provide a time range (5-10 minutes), depending on how accurate you want to be.

While you can also randomly send through "time card" items to refine this further (essentially a fake item that purely has the purpose of calculating how long it takes to get through the system), you can just send this info with every item instead.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting concept. I do have wide ranging processingTimes, but have been able to normalize this and buffer my time to get close enough. I appreciate the fresh perspective and it has solved my problem well enough.